# "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'type' and 'type'" when trying to multiply two variables

Tags: python, function, file, module, program-entry-point

I want to call the functions from another file in my main function file in python but I always get an error. I am trying to call the area and hypothenuse functions from the triangle file into the main function file to calculate it inputing the figures:

```
# triangle.py
def hypotenuse(a, b):
    a = float
    b = float
    c = sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2)
    return c

def area(x, y):
    x = float
    y = float
    z = (x * y) / 2
    return z

# main.py
def main():
    from triangle import hypotenuse
    from triangle import area
    area(3, 4)
    hypotenuse(5, 6)
main()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jemimah/PycharmProjects/venv/usermodule.py", line 6, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Jemimah/PycharmProjects/venv/usermodule.py", line 4, in main
    area(3,4)
  File "C:\Users\Jemimah\PycharmProjects\triangle.py", line 14, in area
    z = (x * y) / 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'type' and 'type'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code of the `area()` function, as that seems to be where the error is occurring

Comment: It sure would help if you posted `triangle.py`.

Comment: @Mimah check your edit suggest. I added `triangle.py`

Comment: `x = float` is a completely meaningless construct in python, at least for your purposes. In python, you don't declare variable types like you do in other languages. Did you mean `x = float(x)`?

Comment: thank you for the comments, i fixed it and realized the x = float was a problem.